# Use document title in header defined in template with KOMA class

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I'm writing a document template as a .tex file, that can simply be included at the beginning of any new document and loads all packages, defines headers, footers etc. called `my_template.tex`.

Inside `my_template.tex`, I use KOMA-Script to style the header like:

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    a4paper,
]{scrarticle}

\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\ohead{Template Name \\ Document Name\\ \small Page \thepage~of \totalpages}
\cfoot{}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
```

I want the user to be able to set the title somewhere inside the document, but use this definition inside the template. Something like:

```
\input{my_template.tex}
...
\begin{document}
...
\title{My Document Title}
...
\end{document}
```

How can I set the `Document Name` inside the header to be `My Document Title`? I would also like the same title for a `\maketitle` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

```latex
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    a4paper,
    head lines=3
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\ohead{%
  Template Name\\%
  \Ifstr{\documentname}{}{}{\documentname\\}%
  \small Page \thepage~of \totalpages
}
\newcommand*\documentname{}

\let\originaltitle\title
\renewcommand*\title[1]{\def\documentname{#1}\originaltitle{#1}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between `scrarticle` and `scrartcl`?

Comment: @Aradnix `scrartcl` is the original class name. `scrarticle` is wrapper class that loads `scrartcl`.